# How to get words from google translate phrasebook?

Tags: java, google-translate

I need some way to get words from my phrasebook in google translate. How can I get all words from Google Translate Phasebook? Are there any java api for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try Firebug to see the GET/POST parameters, then look for something like Curl in Java to send those parameters and finally parse the HTTP response. 
Google Translate uses ajax to send and receive the HTTP requests and Firebug is the best tool for that.